# SetLayoutParams In View Cannot be Applied to int

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set the layout params for a view component, but the Android Studio shows me this error `SetLayoutParams In View Cannot be Applied to int`. This is the first time I'm experiencing this as I could do this without any problem in earlier versions of Android Studio.
[image]

Why is that so and what is the solution?

Comment: `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` is an integer constant. `TextView.setLayoutParams()` method expect an object of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`

Comment: `(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50));  `

Answer (score 2):

**You have to initialize new Object with 2 parameters .**

use this ....

```
tt.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

instead of this....

```
tv.setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

these are the constructor    [VIEWGROUP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

[image: o]

**NOTE:-You are actually applying int instead of View.**

`ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` is **int value** which **value is -2.**

Comment: No difference, Same problem  !